# How to execute orderly too many function? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
 function first()  
  { 
   alert('FIRST');
  }

 function second()  
  { 
   alert('SECOND');
  }

 function third()  
  { 
   alert('THIRD');
  }
```

I want to execute all this function orderly after the first one is finished.

I was using `setTimeout` but this will also have an error depending of how each of the function proccesses.

For example if i set `setTimeout` in the second and third function, but what if the first function contains 
some sort of codes that can't be executed immediately?

Please help me.

Comment: Is any of those functions asynchronous? If not, simply doing `first(); second(); third();` in that order would suffice.

Comment: you should look into async/await. The flow would be much clear than using setTimeout yourself

Comment: I don't like the potential value of this question; as it currently stands, it seems too vague to be useful to future visitors. What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Thanks and i appreciate all the answers and comments. I'm just starting to learn more about `Javascript`. I've simplified my question so that others will be able to understand it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is this.

```
 function first()  
 { 
    alert('FIRST');
    this.second(); // Call second function when first one is done...
 }

 function second()  
 {  
    alert('SECOND');
    this.third(); // Call third when second function is done... 
 }

 function third()  
 { 
    alert('THIRD');
 }

 first(); // This will execute first...
```

Apart from this way , You have also many ways to call functions in a order.

You can use,

1) Async/await,

2) Callbacks,

3) promises (bluebird , promise)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try all of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are going for. As others have posted, since your current functions are synchronous, you can just call them one after another.

```
first()
second()
third()
```

BUT, you did mention that "what if they were delayed". So, how do we make sure that as one completes, we can then call the second, then the third etc...

You have to get an understanding of promises. These are sorta like a contract that at some time in the future you will be given either a notice of success or failure.

It's like the program/operation saying "I will give you an answer to your question in a bit, but first let me try to get you what you want...". I guess everyone has different interpretations on how to "understand concepts". I just like to say something like "I have a question....do your research and let me know if their is an answer"... then your application comes back with "Success: here is your answer" or "Reject: Sorry, can't answer".

So, given your code. We need to take each of those functions and send their "questions" thru a promise wrapper, so that we can wrap the "question" in this promise concept I was talking about.

The wrapper is simple. It takes a delay, and the value you want to "resolve". You don't have to pass the value....I just did so we get the idea of passing off to a promise, and expecting a return.

```
function promiseWrapper(time, value) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      return setTimeout(() => resolve(`passed value: ${value}`), time);
   })
} 

async function first()  
  { 
   const result = await promiseWrapper(3000, 'first called');
   console.log("FIRST RESULT", result)
   return result
  }

 async function second()  
  { 
    const result = await promiseWrapper(1000, 'second called');
    console.log("FIRST RESULT", result)
    return result
  }

// this runs each at the same time, and each function
// returns a value irrespective of the others functions. BUT
// all values are returned at the same time... ala Promise.all
async function runAllParallel() {
   const results = await Promise.all([first(), second()]);
   console.log(results); 
}

// this is what you asked for.. only fire each function after 
// the preceding one finishes.
async function runAllSerial() {
   await first(), 
   await second();
}

//runAllParallel()
runAllSerial()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to use this kind of method.

Answer (score 0):

Give us more detail on the nature of your functions.

if the functions are synchronous, just call in sequence: `first(); second(); third();`

Otherwise you need to attach to the callbacks of your asynchronous function and call the next function in order.

Comment: I am new about callbacks. I'm starting to learn about it. Thanks.